# Loading money datatype to excel in SSIS

Tags: excel, ssis, type-conversion, currency

I have a field in a SQL table which is of datatype 'money'. I'm loading the contents of this table to an excel destination using SSIS. Now the excel destination needs this money column to have a $ symbol i.e. basically format it to currency. It doesn't seems to work. I need to manually format the output each time. I can convert it using Derived column in SSIS and add a $ symbol; This would however convert the field to a string field and load it to excel which is not what I want.
Any inputs?

I tried adding a sample row with proper formatting and hiding the row in the excel destination before loading it. That doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden sample row works for me. Here are the steps I suggest:

1. Create Excel file with column datatype defined as Currency with $ at
   the start.
2. Add column name, e.g. "Total" In the second row put 0 in the cell.
   Ensure that it is shown as "$0,00".
3. Create data flow with source as your SQL Server table and Excel
   destination created based on your Excel file. Define mapping, etc.
4. Right click on created Excel destination, click "Show Advanced
   Editor", go to "Input and Output Properties". Open "External
   Columns" list and ensure that "Total" column is picked automatically
   as currency [DT_CY]

Check this post as well: http://sqlserversolutions.blogspot.com/2011/10/numeric-gets-converted-to-text-in-excel.html